# Does $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\xi_n}{n}$ for poisson distribution exists?

Tags: probability-theory

How can i find, does $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\eta_n}{n}$ where $\eta_n$ has poisson distribution with  $\lambda = n$ exists?

Answer (score 1):

This really depends on what you mean by "exist". Since $\eta$ is random variable, it is really a function $\eta: \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, where $\Omega$ is the underlying probability space.

If you mean "what is the distribution of $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{\eta_n}{n}$, if it exists", then notice the moment generating function of $\frac{\eta_n}{n}$ can be shown to be $$e^{n(e^{\frac{t}{n}} - 1)}$$

Taking the limit of the above as $n\rightarrow \infty$ gives us

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} e^{n(e^{\frac{t}{n}} - 1)} = e^t$$

which is the moment generating function of the [degenerate distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degenerate_distribution) centered at $1$.

SO, we can say that $\frac{\eta_n}{n}$ converges to $1$ in distribution as $n\rightarrow \infty$

Comment: And in probability!

Comment: @SangchulLee I answered this question a few months ago; there is actually almost sure convergence.

Comment: True to both! Just thought this was a pretty simple proof that it converges in *some* manner since the type of convergence wasn't specified.

Comment: @Math1000 Sounds interesting, I will have a look on that!